# Radzen DataGrid possible bug when adding a new row

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, radzen

When adding a new row, I clicked the **Add New Order** button, edit template opens. If I click somewhere like **Vendor** filter, the **Add New Order** button stays ***disabled*** as in the screenshot and the edit template disappears.

[image]
And also after clicking **Add New Order** fill the necessary fields/clicking the **SaveRow** button, this newly added row doesn't appear on the data grid until I refresh the page. How can I make it appear without refreshing the page?

By the way, I am using **SQL Server Express 2019**.

Hope you can help me.

Here is the code:

```
@page "/orders"
@using IMS.CoreBusiness
@using IMS.Plugins.EFCore.Migrations
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.Order
@using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.OrderDetail
@using System.Globalization


@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IViewAllOrdersUseCase ViewAllOrdersUseCase
@inject IAddOrderUseCase AddOrderUseCase
@inject IEditOrderUseCase EditOrderUseCase
@inject IAddOrderDetailUseCase AddOrderDetailUseCase
@inject IEditOrderDetailUseCase EditOrderDetailUseCase
<style>
    #wrapper { overflow: auto; }

    #c1 { float: right; }

    #c2 { float: right; }
</style>

<h1>Orders</h1>
<RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add New Order" Click="@InsertRow" Disabled="@(_orderToInsert != null)"/>
<RadzenDataGrid @ref="_grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="7" AllowSorting="true" RowClick="RowClick" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Single"
                Data="@_orders" TItem="Order" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow" @bind-Value="@SelectedOrders"
                ShowExpandColumn="true" ShowPagingSummary="true" AllowColumnResize="true">
    <Template Context="order">
        <RadzenCard Style="margin-bottom: 20px">
            Vendor:
            <b>@order?.VendorName</b>
        </RadzenCard>
        <RadzenTabs>
            <Tabs>
                <RadzenTabsItem Text="Order Details">
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <RadzenButton Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add Order Detail" Click="@(() => InsertDetailRow(order.Id))" Disabled="@(_detailToInsert != null)"/>
                        <RadzenButton Icon="save" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" Text="Save Details" id="c2" Click="@(args => SaveRowDetails(SelectedOrders.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails))"/>
                        <RadzenButton Icon="border_color" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px" Text="Edit Details" id="c1" Click="@(args => EditRowDetails(SelectedOrders.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <RadzenDataGrid @ref="_gridDetail" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" Data="@order.OrderDetails" 
                    TItem="OrderDetail" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRowDetail" RowCreate="@OnCreateRowDetail" AllowColumnResize="true" AllowColumnPicking="true" ShowPagingSummary="true" ColumnWidth="150px">
                        <Columns>

                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Id" Title="Product Number"/>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductCode" Title="Code">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ProductCode" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="ProductCode"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Product Code is required" Component="ProductCode" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductName" Title="Name">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ProductName" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="ProductName"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Product Name is required" Component="ProductName" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="UnitCost" Title="Unit Cost">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenNumeric TValue="double" Min="1" @bind-Value="orderDetail.UnitCost" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="UnitCost"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Unit Cost is required" Component="UnitCost" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                                <Template Context="detail">
                                    @string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", detail.UnitCost)
                                </Template>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", SelectedOrders?.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.UnitCost))</b>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="BuyQuantity" Title="Buy Qty">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenNumeric TValue="int" Min="1" @bind-Value="orderDetail.BuyQuantity" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="BuyQuantity"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Buy Quantity is required" Component="BuyQuantity" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("tr-TR"), "{0:G}", SelectedOrders?.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.BuyQuantity))</b>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="SellQuantity" Title="Sell Qty">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenNumeric TValue="int" Min="1" @bind-Value="orderDetail.SellQuantity" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="SellQuantity"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Sell Quantity is required" Component="SellQuantity" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("tr-TR"), "{0:G}", SelectedOrders?.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.SellQuantity))</b>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="TotalBuyPrice" Title="Total Buy">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenNumeric TValue="double" Min="1" @bind-Value="orderDetail.TotalBuyPrice" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="TotalBuyPrice"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Total Buy Price is required" Component="TotalBuyPrice" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", SelectedOrders?.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.TotalBuyPrice))</b>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="TotalSellPrice" Title="Total Sell">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenNumeric TValue="double" Min="1" @bind-Value="orderDetail.TotalSellPrice" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="TotalSellPrice"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Total Sell Price is required" Component="TotalSellPrice" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", SelectedOrders?.FirstOrDefault()?.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.TotalSellPrice))</b>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ShippingNumber" Title="Shipment">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ShippingNumber" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="ShippingNumber"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Shipping Number is required" Component="ShippingNumber" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="TrackingNumber" Title="Tracking Number">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.TrackingNumber" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="TrackingNumber"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Tracking Number is required" Component="TrackingNumber" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Description" Title="Description">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.Description" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="Description"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Description is required" Component="Description" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Status" Title="Status">
                                <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                                    @*<RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.Status" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="Status"/>*@
                                    <RadzenDropDown AllowClear="true" TValue="string" Class="w-100" Data=@detailStatusList @bind-Value="orderDetail.Status" Name="Status"/>
                                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Status is required" Component="Status" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="OrderId" Title="Order Id" />
                            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Context="orderDetail" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
                                <Template Context="detail">
                                    <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRowDetail(detail))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                                    </RadzenButton>
                                </Template>
                                <EditTemplate Context="detail">
                                    <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => SaveRowDetail(detail))">
                                    </RadzenButton>
                                    <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => CancelEditDetail(detail))">
                                    </RadzenButton>
                                </EditTemplate>
                            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </RadzenDataGrid>
                </RadzenTabsItem>

            </Tabs>
        </RadzenTabs>
    </Template>
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Id" Title="Order ID" Width="120px"/>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="CustomerName" Title="Customer" Width="200px">
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.CustomerName" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="CustomerName"/>
                <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Customer Name is required" Component="CustomerName" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="VendorName" Title="Vendor" Width="200px">
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.VendorName" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="VendorName"/>
                <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Vendor Name is required" Component="VendorName" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="OrderDateTime" Title="Order Date" Width="200px">
            <Template Context="order">
                @($"{order.OrderDateTime:dd/MM/yyyy}")
            </Template>
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value="order.OrderDateTime" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" Class="w-100"/>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="Status" Title="Status" Width="100px">
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                @*<RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.Status" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="Status"/>*@
                <RadzenDropDown AllowClear="true" TValue="string" Class="w-150" Data=@orderStatusList Name="Status" @bind-Value="order.Status"/>
                <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Status is required" Component="Status" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Property="DoneBy" Title="Employee">
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="order.DoneBy" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="DoneBy"/>
                <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="DoneBy is required" Component="DoneBy" Popup="true" Style="position: absolute"/>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Order" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
            <Template Context="order">
                <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRow(order))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
                </RadzenButton>
            </Template>
            <EditTemplate Context="order">
                <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => SaveRow(order))">
                </RadzenButton>
                <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => CancelEdit(order))">
                </RadzenButton>
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>

    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

@code {
    // Options to display in the roles dropdown when editing a user
    readonly List<string> detailStatusList = new() { "Getting ready", "Being supplied", "Shipped", "At customs", "In warehouse", "Sent to customer" };
    readonly List<string> orderStatusList = new() { "Completed", "Cancelled", "Continues"};

    IList<Order?> SelectedOrders { get; set; }
    //IList<OrderDetail> _selectedDetails;
    //Order order { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<Order?> _orders = new List<Order?>();

    RadzenDataGrid<Order?> _grid;
    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDetail> _gridDetail;

    Order? _orderToInsert;
    OrderDetail? _detailToInsert;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _orders = await ViewAllOrdersUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
        SelectedOrders = new List<Order?> { _orders.FirstOrDefault() };

    }

    private async Task RowClick(DataGridRowMouseEventArgs<Order> mouseClick) {
        //order.Id = mouseClick.Data.Id;
        await _grid!.ExpandRow(mouseClick.Data);
    }
    //void RowRender(RowRenderEventArgs<Order> args)
    //{
    //    if (args.Data.OrderDetails != null)
    //        args.Expandable = args.Data.OrderDetails.Count > 0;
    //    else
    //    {
    //        args.Data.OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
    //    }
    //}


    //protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    //{
    //    if (firstRender)
    //    {
    //        _grid.ExpandRow(_orders.FirstOrDefault());
    //        StateHasChanged();
    //    }

    //    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    //}


    private async Task InsertRow()
    {
        _orderToInsert = new Order
        {
            OrderDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>()
        };
        await _grid.InsertRow(_orderToInsert);
    }

    private async Task InsertDetailRow(int id)
    {
        _detailToInsert = new OrderDetail
        {
            OrderId = id
        };
        await _gridDetail.InsertRow(_detailToInsert);
    }

    private async Task OnCreateRow(Order? order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            await AddOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);
        }
    }

    private async Task OnCreateRowDetail(OrderDetail? orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            await AddOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetail);
        }
    }

    private async Task OnUpdateRow(Order order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        if (order != null)
        {
            await EditOrderUseCase.ExecuteAsync(order);
        }
    }

    private async Task OnUpdateRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            await EditOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetail);
        }
    }

    private void CancelEdit(Order? order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        _grid.CancelEditRow(order);
    }

    private void CancelEditDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }

        _gridDetail.CancelEditRow(orderDetail);
    }


    async Task EditRow(Order? order)
    {
        await _grid.EditRow(order);
    }

    async Task EditRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        await _gridDetail.EditRow(orderDetail);
    }

    async Task EditRowDetails(IList<OrderDetail?> SelectedOrders)
    {
        foreach (var detail in SelectedOrders)
        {
            await _gridDetail.EditRow(detail);
        }
    }

    async Task SaveRow(Order? order)
    {
        if (order == _orderToInsert)
        {
            _orderToInsert = null;
        }

        await _grid.UpdateRow(order);

    }

   
    async Task SaveRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }

        await _gridDetail.UpdateRow(orderDetail);
    }

    async Task SaveRowDetails(IList<OrderDetail?> SelectedOrders)
    {
        foreach (var detail in SelectedOrders)
        {
            if (detail == _detailToInsert)
            {
                _detailToInsert = null;
            }

            await _gridDetail.UpdateRow(detail);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Adding this to **SaveRow** did the trick, someone may need it.

```
_orders = await ViewAllOrdersUseCase.ExecuteAsync(user);
StateHasChanged();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first question, your button is controlled in the top level component by whether `_orderToInsert` is null.  The click event inside the data grid is restricted to the data grid.  What sets `_orderToInsert` to null and tells the `RadzenButton` to re-render?  I'm unfamiliar with Radzen, so I don't know if there's and event raised that you can hook into (on a quick peek it looks like the only suitable event is `LoadData`).

On the second question, you populate `_orders` in `OnInitializedAsyc`.  Your save routines call back into the service to add the record, but you don't refresh `_orders`.  Your save routines need to refresh the displayed list once they have completed.

Comment: totally agree with the second answer, trying to figure it out how to make button enabled on my first question

Comment: There are two callbacks for the DataGrid components - `OnFilterKeyPress` and `OnFilter` - which may be your solution.  Put in some handler code to check if and when these are called.  There's also `OnDataChanged` which appears to be a catchall.  https://blazor.radzen.com/docs/api/Radzen.Blazor.RadzenDataGrid-1.html

Comment: Tried all of the above but no luck, set a breakpoint but none of them called. Could there be something I missed?

Comment: Not that I can see.  You'll probably need to rethink the button.  I'm not a great fan of libraries, I seem to find the walls pretty quickly!  PS I did get the message from the other question :-)

Comment: _grid.Reload() refreshes the grid without refreshing the page.